# Remote desktop without a physical screen plugged in

Tags: server, graphics, multiple-monitors, display

I set up an old computer on desktop Ubuntu with the goal of having it as a NAS, media server, and torrent machine. After quite a long time and tries with FreeNAS, and Ubuntu server, I finally tried a normal desktop distro and got it working near perfectly. However, now that I've unplugged the screen, when I connect via vnc, the desktop is completely black (and no, it isn't a problem with the power saving settings). Is there any way to force the screen to act as though there's a physical screen or otherwise get it to work?